# Does a cable modem have its own MAC and IP addresses or is it just passing out your router's MAC address and IP address?

Tags: cable-modem

Please correct me if I’m wrong:

I have a SOHO router at home that is plugged to my cable modem.
My idea is that a MODEM is just modulating the digital signal coming out of my router into the analog carrier signal that travels through the cable to the ISP (and demodulating it when receiving it from the ISP).
So my idea is that, the MODEM itself, does not have a MAC address or IP address, it is just passing out your router’s MAC address and global IP address.
What confuses me is that I heard that the MODEM itself has its MAC address at the bottom.  Why would a MODEM have its own MAC address if it doesn’t have a network card?, I mean: it’s the router that has a network card that it needs to connect to the internet, right?...and much less its own IP address.

Any clarification much appreciated.
(note: I read other similar posts here regarding this but none made it clear at all)

I've added this image after I read some of your answers:
[image]

Comment: "Why would a MODEM have its own MAC address if it doesn’t have a network card?" - It does; You connected your cable modem to your router using an Ethernet cable. By doing this you assigned your router an intranet IP address using DHCP. Your router then assigns intranet IP addresses of it's own using DHCP.

Comment: Over the decades I've had more than one occasion to talk to the modem.  It's definitely a separate entity, reached by a different IP than the router and returning very different screens than the router does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, nowadays a "modem" frequently *is* a router, as putting it all on the same device tends to be cheaper and simpler to set up. (Same reason why your router also does Wi-Fi even if that's not really a router's job.)

Second, though:

> My idea is that a MODEM is just modulating the digital signal coming out of my router into the analog carrier signal that travels through the cable to the ISP (and demodulating it when receiving it from the ISP).

Originally, yes, but that stopped being true *very* quickly. Even the old analog dial-up modems quickly became more than just modems when they learned how to automatically dial a phone number – they became full computer-controlled peripherals, where the data sent by a computer to a dial-up modem would at first be interpreted as commands to the modem itself (e.g. to dial or to set various parameters), and only after switching to "data" mode during a call would the modem actually do the job of a modulator/demodulator.

So the job of a "modem" now isn't only to modulate a signal, but to do whatever is necessary to establish a data link, which may include "calling" a specific service, negotiating the modulation parameters with the other end, adjusting to physical link conditions, etc. Depending on what network technology is being used, the actual data being put on the wire will often be more than the data you're sending if the modem needs to request a particular "virtual circuit" or something such.

And even once the link is established, the modem may actually need to send its own packets to be admitted to the network (e.g. 802.1X) before it can start forwarding your data, and it might have a MAC address (or an IMEI, etc.) for that purpose.

I don't know how DOCSIS works, but Wi-Fi access points are a simpler example: although they *look like* a transparent layer-2 bridge that ordinarily wouldn't need a MAC address, there's actually quite a bit of operational communications (control frames) being exchanged underneath that facade, e.g. "beacon" frames, "association request" frames, etc – all of which are sent from or to the Wi-Fi access point's own MAC address.

The same applies to GPON, DOCSIS, Homeplug (powerline), ADSL – the modem does a lot of behind-the-scenes communications with the "other end" to provide the illusion of being a transparent bridge. (You could say that even dial-up modems had a kind of a "MAC address" – the phone number.)

Only fiber Ethernet (not GPON) is an exception, in that the fiber media converters are really just media converters and nothing else.

---

The modem may talk on the Ethernet/LAN side as well, having an IP address so that you could configure it over the network.

So in OSI terminology, "modems" typically work as layer-2 bridges – same as an Ethernet switch – and forward data frames, not just any arbitrary signal. A modem that receives data over Ethernet from your router will receive a *whole* Ethernet frame into memory as bytes, paying attention to the MAC addresses and everything, possibly encapsulate it in some other frame type (cable uses DOCSIS, ADSL uses ATM), before actually sending it out.

But because the bridge looks at MAC addresses, it can also act as a host on its own – internally it's not a straight path in/out but a 3-way junction where frames sent to the bridge's own MAC address will take the side path to the bridge's CPU, which can have an IP address and host a webpage for configuration (like your router does).

(This can be easier to understand if you look at Ethernet switches rather than cable modems – while basic switches don't have a MAC address, plenty of the larger ones do. A managed "8-port" switch really has 9 ports, one of which leads to the switch's own CPU which is a host on the same network as the 8 external ports, allowing you to configure the switch.)

Even then, with some connection types it's not even enough for a "modem" to be only a bridge – for example, 4G/LTE cell networks are just completely incompatible with Ethernet networks and a standalone 4G modem has to handle all the way up to IP layer (layer 3). Such modems unavoidably *are* routers as well, so they have a MAC address the same way a router does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a cable modem has a MAC address.

Please see  [Cable Modem MAC address](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/39686/does-modem-has-unique-mac-address-on-your-home-network#:%7E:text=Yes.,the%20bottom%20of%20the%20Modem.)

All computing type devices that communicate over LAN or over Internet have MAC addresses.

MAC and IP addresses work together to associate packets with a device.

Comment: Just to be clear: so the modem's MAC and IP address are unique and different to the router's MAC and global IP addresses?  or is it the same as the router's MAC and IP address?

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Modem MAC is unique from Router MAC (very occasional errors in MAC addressing).  That is not the same as IP address. The modem external IP can pass to the router if the modem is bridged. I do this. That passes the IP address to the router. Does not have to but can be done.

Comment: @Antonio23249 - It's unlikely your router even has an Internet IP address assigned to it.

Comment: If the modem is not bridged,  correct - no internet IP in the router. If bridged, the external internet IP shows up in the router WAN setting.  That is how my own routers work and have worked (Cisco RV series).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be a nuisance, I read all you said and I’d like to make sure I understood well.

So (see my picture above), you’ll usually get 4 MAC addresses and IP addresses (if your modem has both internet facing and local facing NIC interfaces).
The two MAC addresses and IP addresses in the MODEM are just used for management.

Like user1686 said, a cable modem works at layer 2 of the OSI model, so, just like a Layer 2 bridge, it doesn’t really “need” a MAC or IP address associated to its ports for its basic activity.  It has an internet facing MAC address and IP address so that the ISP can manage it.  It has LAN MAC and IP address so you can manage it.

The router has also a MAC address and IP address on each side.  The internet facing IP address is the “true” public IP address for your network (the one you get when you google “what’s my IP address), shown as IP address 3 in the picture.

I also read that some ISPs may use CGNAT to cram multiple users behind a single external IP address, but this isn’t used much, in which case your router won’t get a truly public IP address, but will be given an address within your provider's network.  The provider will then use NAT and use a public IP address to connect you to the internet.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, but that's missing the most important point that the modem may need a MAC address not for management reasons, but simply to establish the data link. I don't know how DOCSIS works, but Wi-Fi access points are a simpler example: although they _look like_ a transparent layer-2 bridge that wouldn't need a MAC address, there's actually quite a bit of operational communications (control frames) being exchanged underneath that facade, e.g. "beacon" frames, "association request" frames, etc – all of which are sent from or to the Wi-Fi access point's own MAC address.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is now quite clear.

Answer (score 0):

I posted a related question on reddit.com and got a great answer
by [frmadsen](https://www.reddit.com/user/frmadsen):

> A cable modem (without an embedded router)
> has both an ip and a mac address. 
> The modem cannot get online without first getting an ip (internal to the DOCSIS network).
>
> To the question here: The destination mac is the router's wan address (the modem is transparent in this process).
>
> Pre DOCSIS 3.0, the modem looked at this mac address to determine if the ethernet frame should be forwarded to the lan side. Post 3.0, it looks at the dsid (functions like a vlan tag). Note: The payload of the frame is encrypted by DOCSIS, so you cannot sniff your neighbor's traffic by using a modified modem. :-)
>
> <sup>— Source: [I’m confused about the MAC address
> and IP address of my cable modem vs my router.](https://www.reddit.com/r/CompTIA/comments/zmujtf/im_confused_about_the_mac_address_and_ip_address/)</sup>